# js files can't be retrieved when requested via //?

Tags: javascript, timeout

My pages may be retrieved over http or https, so I've added a `//` before filenames to respect requests over both protocols:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/script/history.js?v=4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/script/history.adapter.jquery.js?v=4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/script/shopfuncs.js?v=14"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/script/jquery-ui-1.10.3.shop.custom.min.js"></script>
```

However, suddenly my site (locally at least) seems to be having difficulties requesting these files.
When I type the full URL's in the address bar, I can successfully request the files, e.g. `www.example.com/script/history.js?v=4`

The response header of these failed files only mentions `Failed to load response data`.

I've never had problems with the `//` before.

My Chrome network tab shows:

[image]

Comment: Does it work through `http` but not `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"failed" could mean a lot of things.

- Most common encounter I get is when a Chrome extension (like AdBlock) blocks the resource.
- Other times, it's when the resource resides on HTTP when on an HTTPS page, which Chrome blocks for security purposes.

You might want to check the Console for details, seeing that there is 13 error logs on it.